# Select some values from a multiple select option based on an array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I managed to select all of the options from a multiselect, however, I am trying to select Test2 and Test3 only. I have an array `$arr` which contains some values I want to select. for example `$arr = ('Test2', 'Test3')`

```
<select id="test" multiple="multiple">
    <option>Test</option>
    <option>Test2</option>
    <option>Test3</option>
    <option>Test4</option>
</select>
```

Selecting all:

```
$('#test option').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Comment: use index to select  like `$('#test option:nth-child(2)').attr('selected', 'selected'); $('#test option:nth-child(3)').attr('selected', 'selected');`

Comment: I need to select based on the value not the index

Comment: `var multi = $('#test').val(), two = multi[1], three = multi[2]; console.log(two); console.log(three);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.

```js
var selOptions = ['Test2', 'Test3'];
$('#test option').each(function() {
//this is the option. If attribute value isn't set explicitly then test is the value
  if (selOptions.indexOf(this.value) > -1)
    this.selected = 1;
});
console.log($('#test option:selected'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="test" multiple="multiple">
    <option>Test</option>
    <option>Test2</option>
    <option>Test3</option>
    <option>Test4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the using ":contains" to target the text itself?

```
$('#test option:contains("Test2"), #test option:contains("Test3")').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

**Edit:**

If you literally want the 2nd and 3rd option regardless of the text, you can use a child selector like so..

```
$('#test option:nth-child(2), #test option:nth-child(3)').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Comment: I just dont want to hard code the values, as my values are in an array

Comment: I see.. I added a simple child selector option ;)

Comment: Thanks, but I dont know the index of the values

Comment: Then you need to rephrase your question. As well as add more information. As it stands, I don't even know what you're asking for.